# Ajax call does not show the status message within the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this small block of code for sending an e-mail from the user's profile, that is suppose to show an error or a success message.

```
// Mensagem para o dono do anúncio
$('#formulario_anunciante').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/auto/usuario/send_contact_email',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            // It reaches here
            console.log(data);
            //
            if (data.type === 'success') {
                $(this).find('div.msg').removeClass().addClass('msg alerta_sucesso').html(data.msg).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            } else {
                $(this).find('div.msg').removeClass().addClass('msg alerta_erro').html(data.msg).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The code is reaching the `console.log`, showing in the console the returned message, but does not do anything with the `div.msg` tag in my form. It is inside of the `#formulario_anunciante` for sure. Also, for testing purposes, I tried to remove the class `msg`, but the tag seems not to be reachable.

I already tried to add `JSON.parse(data)` and remove the `dataType: 'json'` but nothing works.

Comment: Need the html where the div is as well, please.

Comment: @RichardTheobald Not needed. It is solved.

Comment: `this` won't be the form; you'd need to capture the form in the `submit` function for use in the success callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside the callback function no longer referrs to `#formulario_anunciante`, since it is out of scope. You need to change the selector:

```
var $this = $('#formulario_anunciante')
if (data.type === 'success') {
                $this.find('div.msg').removeClass().addClass('msg alerta_sucesso').html(data.msg).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            } else {
                $this.find('div.msg').removeClass().addClass('msg alerta_erro').html(data.msg).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
            }
```

Comment: That was it. I dot recall having to do this.

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes That's what even I did, and answered first. Anyway.

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes, you should accept GabrielMFernandes's answer, he was, in fact, first.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry, there are only 7 seconds between the answers and I did not check yours previously, but you were faster and since its basically the same solution I shall delete mine once OP accepts yours.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin No no, don't delete. That's okay. You do have an upvote from me. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Inside the `success` function, the `this` refers to the AJAX Object. So try to make a copy of the original variable to `$this` and use it like this:

```
$('#formulario_anunciante').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/auto/usuario/send_contact_email',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      // It reaches here
      console.log(data);
      //
      if (data.type === 'success') {
        $this.find('div.msg').removeClass().addClass('msg alerta_sucesso').html(data.msg).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
      } else {
        $this.find('div.msg').removeClass().addClass('msg alerta_erro').html(data.msg).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
      }
    }
  });
});
```